# Getting max length of a varchar(max) from syscolumns in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
select  c.name, t.name, c.length   
from syscolumns c
```

c.length gives me -1 for any column that has max e.g varchar(max)

What should I do to get length ?

Answer (score 7):

The data type of length on sys.columns is a smallint, whilst the max length of the varchar(max) is 2.1 billion, so it has a problem holding the real length. The -1 is in the documentation for denoting a varchar(max), varbinary(max), nvarchar(max) and xml.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106(v=sql.100).aspx

If you really need the number, then you would need a case statement to replace -1 with (2^31)-1

If you want to get the length of physical data, then you need to max / min / avg the appropriate lengths on the tables with the data on it based on what you need that information for. When querying the length of the field, `DATALENGTH` returns the bytes used, `LEN` returns the characters count.

Answer (score 5):

-1 means that the column is of type `max`. The max length is then the `max` type, as per documentation. MAX types have a maximum length of 2GB if the FILESTREAM attribute is not specified, or a max size limited only by the [disk size available](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx):

> The sizes of the BLOBs are limited only by the volume size of the file
>   system. The standard varbinary(max) limitation of 2-GB file sizes does
>   not apply to BLOBs that are stored in the file system.

Therefore your question really doesn't have an answer. You can ask what is the actual size of any actual in the table value, using [`DATALENGTH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

As seen [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx):

Variable-length, non-Unicode character data. n can be a value from 1 through 8,000. max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes. The storage size is the actual length of data entered + 2 bytes. The data entered can be 0 characters in length. The ISO synonyms for varchar are char varying or character varying.

---

In other words, max = 2147483647 bytes if all the possible space is occupied..

Answer (score 0):

The length of the column in each row could vary. Hence the result of -1

Comment: An original interpretation :). But the same can be said about any VAR type, like VARCHAR(100): the length of each row could vary between 0 and 100. Yet the length is 100, not -1. -1 really means MAX type, is a convention.